# Py2Exe and Easgui

Tags: python, module, py2exe, easygui

I am trying to convert a py file to an exe.
Here is the code for my setupfile

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["mycode.py"])
```

When I use cmd, it says:
Import Error: No module named easygui

How do I let py2exe know about the easygui? As well as the numpy and mathplotlib (all are used in mycode.py)

Comment: Does it fail with import errors when you run the resulting exe, or does the py2exe build process fail?

Comment: It doesn't even create the exe

Answer (score 1):

First, use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It is newer and better (though I have used py2exe until switching to pyinstaller) And it seems to have much better recipes for finding your included libs.

But for py2exe, you will need to expand that setup.py a bit more to tell it what to include (since they are probably hidden imports)

```
setup(
    console=["mycode.py"],
    options={
        "py2exe": {
            "includes": ["easygui"],
            "bundle_files": 1
        },
    },
    zipfile = None,
)
```

If this fails to build, then `easygui` is not in your PYTHONPATH properly. Make sure you are not doing something special in your script to add a pythonpath, which would not be visible to py2exe.

You may need to do a little more work with this file for numpy and matplotlib. See [this wiki for help](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules)

Comment: Thank you this helped, I have a new error now, it now creates the dist file and actually seems to be recognizing the easygui and matplot lib,however when finding dlls this comes:                                                               ***finding dlls needed***                                                           error:ligbk-win32-2.0-0.dll: No such file or directory

Comment: I downloaded that dll and now when i use cmd again it says I now need libgobject-2.0-0.dll

Comment: Depending on the lib you may have a number of dlls to add. Is this for numpy or matplot? Did you follow the wiki for those modules?

Comment: yea i downloaded numpy and mathplotlib from there, I can just keep downloading the dll files separately?

Comment: Well any dll files that you need should be on your system already from installing the packages. The problem is that py2exe needs to know where they are. I don't have much windows experience packaging numpy or matplotlib, but I highly recommend you try pyinstaller. It should at least try a bit harder to get it working out of the box.

Comment: Okay I made the exe file! now when i run the program, it says"Run time error cannot find the mathplotlib files

Comment: Btw when i created the exe, here was the message====================

Comment: *** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which
you may or may not need to distribute them.
Make sure you have the license if you distribute an
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to t
   OLEAUT32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
   MSVCP90.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\MSVCP90.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll

Answer (score 0):

Relative to the issue of the specific dll's mentioned, I had similar issues but fixed those problems by specifically excluding those in the setup lie so:

```
setup(
    console=['DET14.py'],
    options={
             'py2exe': {
                        'packages' : ['matplotlib', 'pytz'],
                        'dll_excludes':['MSVCP90.DLL',
                                        'libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll',
                                        'libgobject-2.0-0.dll',
                                        'libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll'],
                        'includes':['scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation',
                            'scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx']
                       }
            },
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
)`
```

I would say try adding that exclude to your setup statement.