# Reading xlsx files in py2exe

Tags: python, pyexcel

I am using `pyexcel_io.get_data` method to read xlsx files for my wxpython application. When I run it with `python main.py`, reading the file works fine and it reads the contents properly. But when I create an executable using py2exe, the code gets stuck in `get_data` function, and also no error is thrown. It seems like the code is just stuck inside the `get_data` function. Googled but could not find any similar occurences of this issue.

Are there any other similar libraries for reading xlsx files? Or is there an existing solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell py2exe about [the hidden imports](http://pyexcel-io.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyinstaller.html):

```
pyexcel_xlsx
pyexcel_xlsx.xlsxr
pyexcel_xlsx.xlsxw
```

Potential solution: [Py2Exe and Easgui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537379/py2exe-and-easgui)

People tried with [pyinstaller with success](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx/issues/19).

Comment: Worked like a charm!! :)